# What is the re-prompt for password on a website called as it pertains to specs

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

On Google and Microsoft sites sometimes you are re-prompted for the password and the email is displayed (but not editable) if the browser is asleep or you haven't had a tab open in an amount of time. What is the verbiage or terminology for this and what "flow" is it part of and is it part of any part of OIDC or OAuth2?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest `prompt=login`

Comment: @jwilleke Thank you, but I'm stuck on the first step "Search, and research" I don't know what I'm trying to research is called so I don't know what to search.